# Magento CE cache mounted to ram?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, session, redis, memcached

Ive done alot of reading that mounting var/sessions and var/cache to ram will give a performance boost. However would this still be beneficial if I am using SSD?

Answer (score 2):

It's always better to put the data you want to cache in Ram memory as is faster than a SSD. RAM is much faster than SSD but volatile, that means if the power is gone then the data is lost.

Also Ram is not only faster but the OS uses it in a complete different way.

This is just to give an example but a tipycal DRAM has a transfer rate of approximately 2-20GB/s, whereas typical SSDs have a transfer rate of 50MB-200MB/s. So it's one to two orders of magnitude slower.

RAM is far more flexible and is truly random access -- any word, any time. By comparison, flash writes have to erase an entire block at a time before writing to it; and there are other problems that need to be dealt with such as wear leveling and bad blocks.

So you have to put a file system on top of SSD to deal with those issues. You can put a file system on top of DRAM (it is called a ramdisk), but you don't have to.

Coming back to magento you could try to use [memcached](https://www.yireo.com/tutorials/magento/magento-performance/1660-storing-magento-sessions-in-memcached-via-socket) to store sessions data and [redis](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce18-ee113/using_redis.html) for block cache.

Comment: Is mounting var/cache and var/sessions to ram just as good as using memcache and redis?

Comment: It depends on what you need or want to do, but if you have multiple app servers is a good idea to store the sessions in a memcached server that can be accessed by all servers. BTW how would you mount var/cache and var/sessions to ram exactly?

Comment: I was going to ask my host to do this http://screencast.com/t/544FMBPyzL
Located at this link https://yoast.com/magento-performance-hosting/ Everything is on one server.

Comment: I just found this nice article that gives an overview of the different options and it benefits: http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/magento-session-storage-which-to-choose-and-why/

Comment: So according to that article there is not much difference. Seems a little hard to believe. Not sure what to do.

Comment: IMO memcached and/or redis seems more stable and easier to mantain, and the performance is very good, plus if you need to scale is not a problem. I don't know how would you handle multiple frontend servers each one with holding their own session data on tmpfs

Comment: Unless memcache has recently grown persistence to disk, it is a BAD choice for sessions. A crash of the memcache process will irreversably nuke all shop carts and login states in your website. Related read: http://www.aerospike.com/blog/shift-dont-shard/ . Finally: Cm_RedisSession has a bot defense. I've written a bit about it [here](https://mrsopacua.wordpress.com/2015/03/28/optimizing-your-magento-instance/) (scroll down to the Sessions sections). It is by far the best choice.